# How to query a button with specific text with react native testing library

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, testing-library, react-native-testing-library

I am trying to query a button with a specific text in react native (yes there is another similar question but it didn't work for me). I want to getByRole the 'Login' Button of my screen but it gets my 'Register' Button as well.

```
 it('renders buttons', () => {
    const {getByRole} = render(<LoginScreen />);
    getByRole('button', {description: 'Login'});
  });
```

This is what i get as error

```
renders buttons

    Expected 1 but found 2 instances with accessibilityRole "button"

      11 |   it('renders buttons', () => {
      12 |     const {getByRole} = render(<LoginScreen />);
    > 13 |     getByRole('button', {description: 'Login'});
         |     ^
      14 |   });
```

And this is the code :

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Card, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native-paper';

const axios = require('axios').default;

export const LoginScreen = props => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();

  const register = () => props.navigation.navigate('Register');
  const home = () => props.navigation.navigate('Home');

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View>
        <Card>
          <Card.Title title="Login" />
          <Card.Content>
            <TextInput
              accessibilityLabel="Username"
              placeholder="example"
              onChangeText={txt => setUsername(txt)}
              defaultValue={username}
            />
            <TextInput
              accessibilityLabel="Password"
              placeholder="***"
              onChangeText={txt => setPassword(txt)}
            />
          </Card.Content>
          <Card.Actions style={style.button}>
            <Button
              onPress={() => {
                axios({
                  method: 'post',
                  url: 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/login',
                  data: {username: username, password: password},
                })
                  .then(response => {
                    console.log('0', response);
                    home();
                  })
                  .catch(error => {
                    console.log('1', error);
                  });
              }}>
              Login
            </Button>
            <Button onPress={register}>Register</Button>
          </Card.Actions>
        </Card>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end'},
});
```

I also tried queries like
`getByText('Login', {selector : 'button'})`
and
`getByRole('button', {name : 'Login'})`

All I want is to get a button with specific text without getting the other button with a different text. But it really feels as if the second argument is getting ignored whatever i do.

Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way around this is to assign the button a testID, and then use getByTestId from react-native-testing-library.

```
// in component
<Button
  testID='LoginButton'
  ...

// in test
const { getByTestId } = render(<LoginScreen />);
expect(getByTestId('LoginButton')).toBeDefined();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getByRole` function accepts only one argument in the React Native version of the Testing Library. That’s why the second argument is being ignored.

You can check it in the source code here: https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/blob/597fa3c4f84b40cccfd28a2babeb90d98dbe7c93/src/queries/a11yAPI.ts#L64

As others already mentioned, you could try `getByText` or `getByTestId`.